# Use only limited keys from $lookup aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to filter data after $lookup aggregation.

Now, I want the only value of location key from child collection, not the whole document. Also if I need the specific key in location i.e zone_id  What should I do? Please help.

I am using below query

// Query

```
db.parent.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
        {
          from: "child",
          localField: "pid",
          foreignField: "pid",
          as: "more"
        } 
       }
])
```

**// Data
// Child collection**

```
 db.child.insert({
  "pid": 1,
  "name": "Max",
  "title": "Top" 
  "status": 1,

  "description": {
    "destination": "jur bagh",
    "community": "abc"
  },
  "location:": {
    "zone_id": "north",
    "city": "jaipur",
    "latitude": "12.121212",
    "longitude": "21.414134"
  }, 
  "created_by": "user_id",
  "modified_by": "user",
  "created_at": "12:00",
  "updated_at": "13:00"
});
```

// parent collection

```
 db.parent.insert({
  "pid": 1,
  "pname": "PQW",
  "rox": "Labs",
  "status": 1,
  "created_by": "smdcd",
  "modified_by": "pink",
  "created_at": "12:00",
  "updated_at": "13:00"
});
```

I want result like this

```
db.parent.insert({
  "pid": 1,
  "pname": "PQW",
  "rox": "Labs",
  "status": 1,
  "created_by": "smdcd",
  "modified_by": "pink",
  "created_at": "12:00",
  "updated_at": "13:00"
"more" [
"location:": {
    "zone_id": "north",
    "city": "jaipur",
    "latitude": "12.121212",
    "longitude": "21.414134"
  }
]


});
```

Comment: Note there is what appears to be a "typo" in your child collection data. The field is named `"location:"` which includes a colon `:` on the end of the name. It's not clear if this is just a mistake in the question or if your actual data contains this error. Thus the "mistake" is considered in response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) here to reference the "single" result from the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and place your new field in the document using [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) where available or otherwise [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) with all fields:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "child",
    "localField": "pid",
    "foreignField": "pid",
    "as": "location"  
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
      "location": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$location.location:", 0 ] }
  }}
])
```

Also note that you seem to have a typo in your field name in the child since it is called: `"location:"` with the colon `:` on the end. Or maybe that's a mistake in just the question.

Produces:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5968821f7dcd6a5f6a9b4b7d"),
    "pid" : 1.0,
    "pname" : "PQW",
    "rox" : "Labs",
    "status" : 1.0,
    "created_by" : "smdcd",
    "modified_by" : "pink",
    "created_at" : "12:00",
    "updated_at" : "13:00",
    "location" : {
        "zone_id" : "north",
        "city" : "jaipur",
        "latitude" : "12.121212",
        "longitude" : "21.414134"
    }
}
```

Based on the data as provided in your question.

Alternately process with [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) if you do intend multiple results:

```
db.parent.aggregate([
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "child",
    "localField": "pid",
    "foreignField": "pid",
    "as": "more"  
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "more": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$more.location:",
        "as": "l",
        "in": { "location": "$$l" }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

With results like:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5968821f7dcd6a5f6a9b4b7d"),
    "pid" : 1.0,
    "pname" : "PQW",
    "rox" : "Labs",
    "status" : 1.0,
    "created_by" : "smdcd",
    "modified_by" : "pink",
    "created_at" : "12:00",
    "updated_at" : "13:00",
    "more" : [ 
        {
            "location" : {
                "zone_id" : "north",
                "city" : "jaipur",
                "latitude" : "12.121212",
                "longitude" : "21.414134"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please note $addFields is only available from MongoDB v3.4.

Comment: @PavK. Pretty well aware of that, which is why I said "where available". It makes little difference anyway, and is merely the the distinction between listing "all" fields with a `1` to include via `$project` or using `$addFields`. The basics of the answer are unchanged by version. You need at least MongoDB 3.2 for `$lookup` anyway, and 3.4 is not exactly a 'new release'.

Comment: @NeilLunn 
when I type mongo in ubuntu 
it shows  MongoDB shell version v3.4.6
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
MongoDB server version: 3.2.15
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match

which still not recognizing $addfields

Comment: @Creator Because it does not matter what the "shell" version is, but rather it's the "server" version that determines what operators are recognized. As noted the answer is still basically the same, with the exception that you must use `$project` and therefore explicitly include all other fields you want to include. Your "server" is MongoDB 3.2. Since it's on `localhost` though, it sounds like you recently installed but never restarted the server instance. If that's what you did, then restart the server so the new 3,4 version will execute. Unix works like that.

Comment: @NeilLunn thanks for such a wonderful explanation, hope it will be helpful for other developers too

Answer (score 0):

Use $project
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

```
,{$project:{
  pid:1,
  pname:1,
  rox:1,
  status:1,
  modified_by:1,
  created_by:1,
  created_at:1,
  updated_at:1,
  more.location:$more.location
}}
// 'name of the field':1 means you want to keep the 'name'.
//  more.location:$more.location means you passing down the data you need.
```

To filter down the results you can add $match into your aggregate
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/

```
,{$match:{
    more.location.zone_id:'north'
}}
```

if you have multiple locations as array but only want to return one, you might want to $unwind array first:

```
,{$unwind:'$more.location'}
```

Comment: It gives me error : 
SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell)

db.parent.aggregate([
        {
          $lookup:
        {
          from: "child",
          localField: "pid",
          foreignField: "pid",
          as: "more"
        } 
       },
      
{$project:{
  pid:1,
  pname:1,
  rox:1,
  status:1,
  modified_by:1,
  created_by:1,
  created_at:1,
  updated_at:1,
  more.location:$more.location
}}

])